# UITapGestureRecognizer blocks UITableViewCell didSelectRowAt but not IBAction

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

UITapGestureRecognizer of base view in a View Controller catches the touch event when user taps at any UITableViewCell within the View Controller. I can solve this problem by adding a delegate to the UITapGestureRecognizer instance and filter out the UITableViewCell.

- BaseView with UITapGestureRecognizer

  - UIButton with IBAction
  - UITableViewCell with didSelectRowAt function

However, I do not understand why the UITapGestureRecognizer does not affect the buttons with the View Controller.

I add a button which links with an IBAction

  `@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    print("buttonAction")
  }`

and also the base view with an UITapGestureRecognizer

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(baseViewTapAction)))  

@objc func baseViewTapAction() {
    print("baseViewTapAction")
  }
```

and also an UITableView with UITableViewCell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("UITableViewCell")
  }
```

The outcome is :
Tap on UIButton:

```
buttonAction
```

Tap on baseView:

```
baseViewTapAction
```

Tap on UITableViewCell:

```
baseViewTapAction
```

Comment: any reason why you are adding gesture to baseView. Isn't tableview full screen? If not, add a subView in baseView that covers the area which tableView doesn't and add gesture to that view and don't mess tableView touch events.

Comment: For example, a gesture recognizer is added to the background of a custom dialog to dismiss a dialog. It is strange that only the touch action of UITableViewCell is intercepted but not the IBAction. What is the documentation that supports behind?